# Format an old computer (doesn't have a CD drive and doesn't allow booting from USB)

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I have an old laptop that I want to reinstall Windows XP on. As mentioned in the title there is no CD drive and the boot menu shows only these 4 options:

1. Hard disk.
2. Floppy (the computer doesn't have a floppy reader either!).
3. Network.
4. CD drive.

So what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the Hard Disk option within the boot menu then picking a sub option that has USB listed in it, if there is one? Or have you checked your bios settings and made your USB drive the first option to boot off of?

Comment: Ignore pre-edit of this comment - I misread that you only wanted to format, when you actually want to reinstall. It has been a very long time since I did it, but you can make bootable Windows XP CD that includes additional drivers.

Comment: @Dispensador the only thing in the sub-menu of "Harddisk" is the internal hard disk. and those 4 options are from the BIOS settings it doesn't show anything about USB

Comment: @Paul But the laptop doesn't have a CD reader.

Comment: From what @Paul said, I would suggest you make a bootable XP ISO with the drivers you need and then turn that into some sort of netboot image and boot off of that. I've never done that sort of thing before though, so I'm not sure how well it would work, but it's at least worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Attach bootable USB drive to the computer and then Go to boot menu, Under the hard drive option just bring the bootable USB or USB hard drive to the top and bring the system primary hard drive to bottom.
If not getting the solution then attach the screen shots of boot menu (BIOS)